# Octopus Package Application Step in TFS Build not picking up files in sub folders

Tags: deployment, tfsbuild, nuget-package, octopus-deploy, octopus

Hi I am using Octopus Deploy Package Application step to package up my website

I specified the Source Path, Output path etc just fine.

If I do not specify the Include files it brings back everything in the folder structure as the package. But I only want to Package certain things like the CSS, views, dll's etc

If i Specify an include form a sub folderlike **/bin/*.dll*** it does not bring the files through, even though this is the exact example they give on the more info icon. but if i specify something in the root like **.png** which is not in a subfolder it works fine.

Anyone faced this issue. Please see image below to see the step setup

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the path below, you'll get all dlls in bin folders:

```
**/bin/*.dll
```

Comment: can you specify a target so it goes into a bin folder inside the package?

Comment: There is no way to achieve this in a single Package Application task. You need to add Copy Files task before Package Application task to copy all dlls into a bin folder, then package this folder.